# jquery enable and disable button on key press

Tags: jquery

I have credit card field and i want to disable the pay button, if the length of the field is < 15 while key press.

I have written the blank field validation, but how do i disable the button, if credit card length is < 15.

### html

```
<form id="creditcaredFrm">
    <input name="cardnum" type="text" placeholder="Card Number" class="textbox iconmastercard required cc-number">
     <input type="text" class="cc-number">
      -- --------- --------
      -- ------- ----- ----

</form>
```

### jquery

```
 activatePayButton('creditcaredFrm');
function activatePayButton(formId){
      $form = $('#'+formId);     
      $form.find(':input').on('change keyup blur', function(event) { // monitor all inputs for changes                                              
      var disable = false;
      $form.find("input[type!='hidden']").each(function(i, el) { // test all inputs for values
        if ($(this).hasClass('required') && $.trim(el.value) === '') {
           disable = true; // disable submit if any of them are still blank
        }                                 
      });                             
      if(disable == true){               
          $form.find('#submitBtn').addClass('disableClick');
        } else{
          $form.find('#submitBtn').removeClass('disableClick');
        }
      });                    
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion

```
$(function() {  
  $(".cc-number').on("change keyup blur",function() {
    $('#submitBtn').toggleClass("disableClick",$.trim(this.value).length<15);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just add this into your function

```
  if($.trim($('.cc-number').val()).length<15)
  {
       disable = true;
  }
```

I would suggest you add that just after the bit that enumerates all other non-hidden inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Just capture the `input event` on `textbox` and check the length of its `val()` and `disable` and `enable` accordingly. For ex.:

```js
$("input[name=cardnum]").on('input',function(){
    if($(this).val().trim().length<15)
      $('.pay').attr('disabled',true);
    else
      $('.pay').attr('disabled',false);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="creditcaredFrm">
    <input name="cardnum" type="text" placeholder="Card Number" class="textbox iconmastercard required cc-number"/>
    <input type="button" disabled value="Pay" class="pay"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will enable button when character length reaches 15, will also restrict number of characters in texbox

```
$('.cc-number').keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode != 8 || e.keyCode != 46) {
        if ($(this).val().length >= 14) {
            $(this).val($(this).val().substr(0, 14));
            $form.find('#submitBtn').removeClass('disableClick');
            return 0;
        } else {
            $form.find('#submitBtn').addClass('disableClick');
        }
    }
});
```